# Gradle: Build file should not contain a package statement

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have a gradle build project that consists of a buildSrc/build.gradle and a project-level build.gradle. The buildSrc/build.gradle compiles a jar dependency that contains a class the project-level build.gradle needs. However, when the project-level build.gradle tries to instantiate an instance of the class pulled in by buildSrc/build.gradle, the build fails. The error is:

> Could not open no_buildscript class cache for build file ~/git/project/build.gradle - Build file ~/git/project/build.gradle should not contain a package statement.

In particular, the project-level build needs the DIGSauceLabsUpdater class that is in the bacon-test-utilities pulled in by buildSrc/build.gradle.

I have tried importing the bacon-test-utilities package into the project-level build and removing the package name from the class in the "def dashUpdater" line. This gave me the same build error.

Can anyone help me understand what else I need to do in order to access a class pulled in by the buildSrc/gradle.build in the the project-level build?

Thank you,

-erzsebet

Here is my buildSrc/build.gradle file:

```
// vim:ft=groovy
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'groovy'


// automated test dependencies
// ---------------------------
dependencies {
def saucerestVersion = "1.0"

compile gradleApi()

// sauce lab's REST client
compile "com.saucelabs.saucerest:saucelabs-saucerest:$saucerestVersion"

// test utilities 
// Note: Needed here for DIGSauceLabsUpdater use in main build.gradle
compile "com.drillinginfo.global:bacon-test-utilities:0.+"
}

// artifacts and maven stuff
// -------------------------
repositories {

    maven {
    url "${project.mavenPublicUrl}/"
}

}
```

Here are the relevant bits of my project-level build.gradle:

```
// vim:ft=groovy
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

// browser driver extensions for acceptance test tasks
ext.drivers = ["firefox", "chrome", "ie"]


// automated test dependencies
// ---------------------------
dependencies {
    groovy "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.6"

    def gebVersion = "0.7.2"
    def seleniumVersion = "2.31.0"
    def lazerycodeVersion = "1.1"
    def saucerestVersion = "1.0"

    // spock
    testCompile "org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.6-groovy-1.8"

    // gradle plugin for test listener code
    compile files('buildSrc/src/main/lib/gradle-plugins-1.2.jar')

    // test utilities
    testCompile "com.drillinginfo.global:bacon-test-utilities:0.+"

    // Drivers
    drivers.each { driver ->
        testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-$driver-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    }
}

// automated acceptance tasks
// --------------------------
// define a TestListener implementation to report test results to Sauce Labs
// THE NEXT LINE IS WHERE THE BUILD CHOKES
def dashUpdater = new com.drillinginfo.global.test.utils.DIGSauceLabsUpdater()

// ensure the tests have access to properties passed in on the command line (-D) 
tasks.withType(Test) {

    gradle.addListener(dashUpdater)
}
```

Here is the stack trace output of my ./gradlew run task:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open no_buildscript class cache for build file '/home/account/git/project/build.gradle' (/home/account/.gradle/caches/1.2/scripts/build_7hf4r97619snd7in1srbtn16n6/ProjectScript/no_buildscript).
Build file '/home/account/git/project/build.gradle' should not contain a package statement.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.cache.CacheOpenException: Could not open no_buildscript class cache for build file '/home/ecarmean/git/bacon/build.gradle' (/home/account/.gradle/caches/1.2/scripts/build_7hf4r97619snd7in1srbtn16n6/ProjectScript/no_buildscript).
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:54)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:26)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$CacheFactoryImpl.doOpenDir(DefaultCacheFactory.java:71)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$CacheFactoryImpl.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:110)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.doOpen(DefaultCacheRepository.java:183)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.doOpen(DefaultCacheRepository.java:133)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$AbstractCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:120)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.compile(ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.java:35)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(CachingScriptClassCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:121)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:463)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:75)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:439)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:434)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:173)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:138)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Build file '/home/account/git/project/build.gradle' should not contain a package statement.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:126)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:67)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CacheInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:80)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CacheInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:65)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.buildCacheDir(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:100)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.access$100(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:36)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$1$1.run(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:82)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:162)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:151)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$1.execute(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:80)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$1.execute(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:70)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withExclusiveLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:73)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.init(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:70)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:46)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: What Gradle is complaining about is a package *statement* (e.g. `package foo.bar`). Apparently there is one in your build script, and that's not allowed.

Comment: The "package statement" Gradle is complaining about is the line:

Comment: The _package statement_ Gradle is complaining about is the line: def dashUpdater = new com.drillinginfo.global.test.utils.DIGSauceLabsUpdater() . I don't understand why it is being interpreted as a package and not as a fully qualified class name. Sorry for the split post! I got called away to a meeting while editing the original comment.

Comment: That's not a package statement. Perhaps the stack trace (`-s`) has a cause?

Comment: That is why I am baffled. If I remove that line of code, the error goes away. Could the problem be because I need to compile the same dependency in both buildSrc/build.gradle and the project-level build.gradle?

Comment: I don't know what's going on. To help more, I'd need a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I will see about creating a small, reproducible example.

Answer (score 5):

If you encounter this error:

```
Build file '...\build.gradle' should not contain a package statement.
```

you should check above path that mentioned and remove package statement in first line of `build.gradle` file.Hope helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

A co-worker and I isolated the problem that caused my gradle build to fail with the "build.gradle should not contain a package statement" error. The jar file containing the dependency had both .class and .groovy files. When we recompiled the jar to include only .class files, the gradle build ran without error and was able to instantiate a class from the (troublesome!) dependency.

I also simplified my build structure by removing the buildSrc/build.gradle. It was no longer needed because there was no source being built in that directory. To pull in the (troublesome!) dependency needed in the project-level build.gradle, I used a buildScript block.

Thank you, Peter Niederwieser, for reading and responding to the question!

Here are the relevant bits of the final build script:

```
// vim:ft=groovy

import com.drillinginfo.global.test.utils.DIGSauceLabsUpdater

apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

// automated test dependencies
// ---------------------------
dependencies {

    groovy "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.6"

    def gebVersion = "0.7.2"
    def seleniumVersion = "2.31.0"
    def lazerycodeVersion = "1.1"
    def saucerestVersion = "1.0"

    // spock
    testCompile "org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.6-groovy-1.8"

    // test utilities
    testCompile "com.drillinginfo.global:bacon-test-utilities:0.+"

    // Drivers
    drivers.each { driver ->
        testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-$driver-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${project.mavenPublicUrl}/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.drillinginfo.global', name: 'bacon-test-utilities', version: '0.0.1+17'
    }
}

/ automated acceptance tasks
// --------------------------
// define a TestListener implementation to report test results to Sauce Labs
def dashUpdater = new DIGSauceLabsUpdater()

// ensure the tests have access to properties passed in on the command line (-D) 
tasks.withType(Test) {

    gradle.addListener(dashUpdater)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue with the following in `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath fileTree(
            dir: "some/directory",
            include: '**/*.jar')
  }
}
```

`some/directory` had source jars so the fix was:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath fileTree(
            dir: "some/directory",
            include: '**/*.jar',
            exclude: '**/-sources.jar')
  }
}
```